# Getting digital signature Error "Error Encountered while BER decoding" using TCPDF

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, tcpdf

I use TCPDF to create digital signature on a PDF document.
I use almost the exact code mentioned here:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps

and I use the same crt file that I use for the SSL on my server when browsing to on my server (linux).
But no matter if the file exists or not, no matter which path it is or which server, **I always get the same error**

I get the error:

**"Error Encountered while BER decoding"**

My server is Centos 6.3(64bit), Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) , PHP Version 5.3.3, MySQLi 5.1.67

My code is:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator('DejaVuSansCondensed');
$pdf->SetAuthor('Soft1');
$pdf->SetTitle('Soft1 Verified');
$pdf->SetSubject('Soft1 Verified');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
// set font
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVuSansCondensed', '', 10);

// set certificate file
$certificatePath = 'file://home/tcpdf.crt';

// set additional information
$info = array
(
    'Name' => 'Soft1',
    'Location' => 'Server',
    'Reason' => 'Signing Document',
    'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.soft1.com',
);

// set document signature
$pdf->setSignature($certificatePath, $certificatePath, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set LTR direction for english translation
$pdf->setRTL(true);

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($printable, true, 0, true, 0);

// create content for signature (image and/or text)
$pdf->Image('themes/default/images/digital_signature.png', 25, 11, 15, 15, 'PNG');

$pdf->setSignatureAppearance(25, 11, 15, 15);               

if($task == 'pdf'){
    //$GLOBALS['log']->fatal("file_name = " . $file_name);
    //$file_name = "hello.pdf";
    $pdf->Output($file_name, "D");
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? 
Searched the web for this error. Almost nothing except old forum posts.

Comment: *the same crt file that i use for the SSL* - have you checked the certificate key usage entry? Probably it is not made for signing. Otherwise please supply a sample signed file for analysis.

Comment: Thank you mkl, i edited the post, no metter what file it is or if it exist in the path i mentioned or not. i always get this error. i can't post the crt file because it has my server detils i it. i posted the code, maybe you can find something wrong with it?

Comment: also can you tell me how to create a new certificate?

Comment: *no metter what file it is or if it exist in the path i mentioned or not. i always get this error* - i don't know which certificate formats TCPDF supports. Probably yours is PEM encoded but a DER encoded one is expected.

Comment: i converted my ssl certificate from PEM format to DER format using openssl:    "openssl x509 -in server_name_com.crt -out certasder.crt -outform DER"  but i still get the error. its amazing! this error is just unsolvable. googled all links on this error and googled all examples of SetSignature() on the web. can't find answer to this bug! what did you mean by "probably not made for signing", could it be that my ssl is not made for signing? how can i know that? thank you :)

Comment: I just looked up the TCPDF docs; [they say](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html) that the first parameter of the `setSignature` call is expected to be the certificate and the second one the private key. You use `$certificatePath` for both. This looks incorrect.

Comment: *could it be that my ssl is not made for signing?* - Yes, certificates have fields denoting their valid uses. But no, Such a problem would most likely give rise to a different error. *how can i know that?* - Open the certificate and look for the key usage and extended key usage entries.

Comment: i debugged the code. i get the error "bool(false) TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file" when i use var_dump of the signing function openssl_pkcs7_sign(). read about it online. can't find solution.... anyone?

Comment: That sounds like during `$pdf->Output($file_name, "D");` something else had already been output. This can occur e.g. if you have space outside the comment your script is in.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and solved it by replacing:

`$certificatePath = 'file:///home/tcpdf.crt';`

**Note the extra '/' in the path**